# Insert foreign key data into SQL Server using c# windows form combobox

Tags: c#, windows, forms, sql-server-2012

I have created two tables `ItemList` and `Salt` in SQL Server 2012.

I want to create a winforms application in C#.

`Salt` (parent table)

```
Salt_ID int NOT NULL,   (primary Key)
Salt_Name var
```

`ItemList` (child table)

```
Item_ID int NOT NULL,    (primary Key)
Salt_ID int NOT NULL,    (foreign Key)
Item Name var
```

Combobox binding detail

```
Datasource = SaltBindingSource
DisplayMember = Salt_Name  (from `Salt` table)
Value Member = Salt_ID     (primary key)
Selected Value = itemListBindingSource-Salt_ID (Foreign Key in Child table)`
```

Now I want to insert combobox primary key data into child table foreign key column and my statement is that

```
(SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Insert into Itemlist(Item_Name,Packing,Salt_ID) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.SelectedValue+ "')", con);)`
```

after this statement I get an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Salt_ID' to data type int.

So please tell me how to insert data into SQL Server database table foreign key column

Comment: this.comboBox1.SelectedValue  is a string value. You have to convert it to an int

Comment: int.Parse(this.comboBox1.SelectedValue)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid aurguments

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: sir given two errors are reflecting on compile time

Comment: It is because "SelectedValue" returns an object. You should use the "SelectedIndex" instead of your combobox.

Comment: i write this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex (Generated error)

Comment: and also int.parse(this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex) generated error

Comment: Sir have you any tutorial vedio related this so which can help me clearly

Answer (score 0):

Set these values to combobox:

```
classTeacher_Combobox.DisplayMember = "teacher_username";
classTeacher_Combobox.ValueMember = "teacher_id";


Insert into Class(item1,item2,teacher_id) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + classTeacher_Combobox.SelectedValue + "')", con)
```

Comment: Now i want to select DisplayMember on foriegn key in other form how is this possible

Comment: You Can Use This Query:
`select teacher_username from TableName where teacher_id = ' " +classTeacher_Combobox.SelectedValue + " ' ;`